# discord.js - How to get the voice status of the bot in a specific server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

In a program, i want to know if the bot is connected or disconnected in any voice channel on a specific server. I see the Voice Statuses on the [wiki](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/VoiceStatus) but i dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You should try read the documentation a little bit more.*
So, from client you have all the guilds that client is: `client.guilds`. Then from that you can filter the guilds, `client.guilds.get('thisID')`. And according to the documentation, with a guild you can get the voiceConnection from that guild with: [`guild.voiceConnection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=voiceConnection).
It will return null if the client is not on any voiceChannel.